# Why doesn't Java provide access to the enum class objects for EnumSet and EnumMap?

Tags: java, collections, enums, enum-map

`EnumSet` has an private field for the value class.  Why not provide public access?

Also, `EnumMap` has private fields for key and value classes.  Same question.

For non-empty sets/maps, it is possible iterate the first element and extract class from a non-null value.  However, for empty sets/maps, this is not possible.

Comment: You should be a C# guy

Answer (score 1):

> EnumSet has an private field for the value class. Why not provide public access?

I cannot think of a technical reason not to.  However, I also can't think of a compelling use-case that requires it.

But ultimately, the answer for your Questions is that it was a decision made by the Java designers, and only they are in a position to explain the actual reasoning for the decisions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is no getter-method for the member class of an `EnumSet` nor for the key class of `EnumMap` is that in order to use these classes effectively, the static type is generally known and used by the programmer, and the type's `Class` can easily be derived from the type name using a class literal.

For example, consider the following enum:

```
enum Direction { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST }
```

You'd use it like this:

```
Set<Direction> wittsEnd = EnumSet.of(NORTH, EAST, SOUTH); // hint: don't go west
```

To add, remove, or check membership in this set, we generally have a `Direction` instance. If we want to create a new set or derive one from an existing set, we'd declare a variable of type `Set<Direction>`. If we want the `Class` object corresponding to the enum type, we just use `Direction.class`. Thus there is generally no need to get the `Class` object out of the `EnumSet` itself.

Similar reasoning applies to `EnumMap`.

I suppose there might be some case out there where one has an instance of an `EnumSet<?>` and you want to create a set of all or none of the enum values, which requires the `Class` object for a type not known at compile time. Such a case would seem to be quite contrived. For such cases, though, one could use this equally contrived technique (i.e., hack) to get the enum class for some unknown EnumSet `s`:

```
Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass =
    EnumSet.copyOf(s).addAll(EnumSet.complementOf(s)).iterator().next().getClass();
```

A similar technique could probably be used to get the key class of an `EnumMap`.